# Split a Gridview in two Grids in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` which gets the data from a `SQL Server` database.

The `GridView` binds when the user select the date from an `CalendarExtender`, because the data is different one day to another, also the rows quantity.

E. G., in Saturdays the `GridView` is filled with 18 rows. In Tuesdays, with 58.

### Concern:

What I need to do is to split the `GridView` in 2 parts (2 `GridViews`). E. G., In tuesdays, 29 rows each `GridView`, in saturdays, 9 rows each.

### I have tried:

To bring the daily data into a `GridView`, called "GVTotal":

```
if (Weekday.Value == "Saturday")
            {
                GVTotal.DataSourceID = SaturdayData.ID;
                GVTotal.DataBind();
            }
```

To count the rows from GVTotal, and divide by 2.

```
int everything = GVTotal.Rows.Count;
            int half = everything / 2;
```

What I want to do now, is to "Copy" the rows from 0 to `half` to `GVPart1`, and from `half` to `everything` to `GVPart2`, in the exactly same order than in `GVTotal`.

I have read that maybe using a `DataTable` will made this possible.
I am not pretty sure how to do that. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a Repeater with two items, one for each GridView. In the example below, the Repeater is rendered as a table with a single row. Each GridView is in a cell of that row, with an empty cell between them.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvHalf" runat="server" >
                ...
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <td style="width: 32px;" />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In order to get the two data sources, you declare two DataTables in your class:

```
private DataTable dtTopHalf;
private DataTable dtBottomHalf;
```

In `Page_Load`, the two DataTables are populated by splitting the full DataTable in two parts, and the data source of the Repeater is set to two boolean values:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local); Integrated Security = True; Initial Catalog=TestMP"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Clients ORDER BY ClientID ASC", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            int halfCount = dt.Rows.Count / 2;
            dtTopHalf = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).Take(halfCount).CopyToDataTable();
            dtBottomHalf = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).Skip(halfCount).CopyToDataTable();
        }

        // Each value in the Repeater indicates if it is the top half or not
        repeater1.DataSource = new List<bool>() { true, false };
        repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The specific data source can then be set for each GridView in the `ItemDataBound` event handler of the Repeater:

```
protected void repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        bool isTopHalf = (bool)e.Item.DataItem;
        GridView gvHalf = e.Item.FindControl("gvHalf") as GridView;
        gvHalf.DataSource = isTopHalf ? dtTopHalf : dtBottomHalf;
        gvHalf.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Note 1**: The Repeater allows to share the same markup for both GridViews. If you prefer, you can declare two separate GridViews in the markup and apply the specific data source to each one in `Page_Load`.

**Note 2**: You need a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` in your project to use some of the LINQ methods mentioned above.

Comment: @Denis Soto - In case you saw my answer yesterday, please note that I made major changes to it afterwards.

Comment: hi ConnorsFan, thank you very much, once more :D. This was the structure that I needed. I will "answer my question" to let everybody knows what I did, but this is the right answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ConnorsFan for the assistance. His answer is the right way to do what I wanted.

As I need to select the date before the data comes in, I wrote Connor's code into my date `Textbox` `OnTextChanged` event, into the `if (Weekday.Value == "<day of the week>")` statement.

This is the solution:

### ASPX:

Updated: Only with one GridView, as reccomended:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table cellspacing="200px" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvHalf" runat="server" BackColor="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-CssClass="tituloshandoff" RowStyle-CssClass="contenidohandoffbatch">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="IDBATCH" DataField="IDBatch" SortExpression="IDBatch" HeaderStyle-CssClass="TituloInvisible" ItemStyle-CssClass="TituloInvisible" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="BATCH" DataField="Nombre" SortExpression="Nombre" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DEALER" DataField="DealerCodigo" SortExpression="DealerCodigo" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CT TIME" DataField="CTStart" SortExpression="CTStart" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="STATUS" DataField="Estado" SortExpression="Estado" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CONTROL">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="botongrid" runat="server" Text="Select" Width="100px" /></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <SeparatorTemplate>
                    <td style="width: 100px;" />
                </SeparatorTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </tr> 
        </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

### C#:

I will show only one day in example:

```
string LaConexion = @"<My Connection String>";
    private DataTable dtTopHalf;
    private DataTable dtBottomHalf;

    protected void TextDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (diasemana.Value == "Monday")
        {
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(LaConexion))
            using (SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT [1Monday].IDBatch, Batch.Nombre, Dealer.DealerCodigo, Batch.CTStart, BatchDatos.Estado FROM [1Monday] INNER JOIN Batch ON [1Monday].IDBatch = Batch.IDBatch INNER JOIN Dealer ON Batch.IDDealer = Dealer.IDDealer LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchDatos ON [1Monday].ID = BatchDatos.ID ORDER BY Batch.CTStart", conexion))
            {
                comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                int halfCount = dt.Rows.Count / 2;
                dtTopHalf = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).Take(halfCount).CopyToDataTable();
                dtBottomHalf = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).Skip(halfCount).CopyToDataTable();
            }
            // Each value in the Repeater indicates if it is the top half or not
            repeater1.DataSource = new List<bool>() { true, false };
            repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

### A Picture:

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer. There is still only one Repeater. With the new markup, the Repeater builds a table with one row. The two GridViews are side by side. The important point: I suggest the Repeater to declare the GridView only once; there will be two GridViews on the HTML page because the Repeater will have two items.

Comment: Oh, let me check that now

Comment: I tried as you say here. You are right. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: Updated! Visually is the same, but this have less code than the other. It's optimized.